# Transformation from Android's tilt and orientation of stylus to tiltX and tiltY

Tags: android, math

I'm calling the followind methods in Android:

```
var tilt = MotionEvent.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_TILT);
var orientation = MotionEvent.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_ORIENTATION);
```

Now I want to translate above values to `tiltX` and `tiltY` defined in W3 spec:

- https://w3c.github.io/pointerevents/#dom-pointerevent-tiltx
- https://w3c.github.io/pointerevents/#dom-pointerevent-tilty

Is there a way to do such a transformation?